# MS Access trying to creating distinct query over time when record should be distinct in the first month only the first time encountered

Tags: ms-access

I've got a table called Result with UserID, RegYear and RegMonth.
the problem is I need to create a DISTINCT on UserID, by RegYear and RegMonth where if a user appears under multiple months or years, he should only be distinct in the earliest period.

For Example:
UserID | RegYear | RegMonth
1      | 2014    | 02
1      | 2014    | 02
2      | 2014    | 02
1      | 2014    | 04
3      | 2014    | 04

UserID "1" should only be shown Once in Month 02 and not at all in Month 04.

in result form:
UserID | RegYear | RegMonth
1      | 2014    | 02
2      | 2014    | 02
3      | 2014    | 04

I hope my problem is clear and that you guys can give me some suggestions?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not clear... especially this part: *should only be distinct in the earliest period*

Comment: Hi<br>I've added a result table view

Answer (score 0):

Consider Group By:

```
SELECT Try.UserID, 
       First(Try.RegYear) AS FirstOfRegYear, 
       First(Try.RegMonth) AS FirstOfRegMonth
FROM Try
GROUP BY Try.UserID
```

Where Try is the name of the table. Note that this may only work in MS Access.

Comment: Hi. had to use the actual date, because if somebody was registered in multiple years and multiple months it would only show one result but with the wrong year and month combination. However you brought me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Select UserID, MIN(RegYear) AS FirstRegisteredYear, MIN(RegMonth) as FirstRegisteredMonth
From Results
GROUP BY UserID

This assumes that your fields are numerical values